# How to make links look like tabs using html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this wireframe I am working from: http://problemio.com/wireframe.pdf

I am trying to make the tabbed items that read like "ongoing discussion | suggested solutions | solution history... "  to look tabbed as they are on the wireframe.

So far I am able to use JavaScript to show/hide the correct elements, but what I am not sure how to do is highlight the tab that is active, and how to draw the lines surrounding the tab.

Here is an example of what I have so far:
http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=179

Even if I make each link a div, how do I toggle between the styling of those divs?

Thanks!!

Comment: Check this article out: http://css-tricks.com/13758-functional-css-tabs-revisited/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're easiest bet will be using jQueryUI Tabs.  Example here http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: good point, but I am kind of new to jQuery.  I got stuck with a similar thing when trying to do autoComplete.  In their example, I don't see how to show/hide various elements although it is very necessary and I am sure its possible.  Btw, are all the tabs crawlable and indexable by google?

Comment: also...I already have all the divs on the page, but in the example, it calls seperate html files.  Is it ok to leave all the elements on the tabs in the same page and just toggle show/hide between them?

Comment: yes, click the View Source button on the "Default Functionality" example on the page i sent you to.  that shows the content on page.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the showing and hiding down and are looking for a non-jQuery option you could try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wqEdj/

It's a basic styling of straight anchor elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS/JS solution that you can run here to see it in action.  JQuery is used, but could easily be replaced with standard JS.  No images required.

The source of this solution:
https://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Another related example with the tabs under the line can be found here: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/JozNqX

```js
$(function() {
  $("li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.tabrow {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 26px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
  position: relative;
}
.tabrow li {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  background: #D1D1D1;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 1px 0 #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #FFF;
  margin: 0 -5px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.tabrow a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabrow li.selected {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
  z-index: 2;
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
.tabrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tabrow li:before,
.tabrow li:after {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  content: " ";
}
.tabrow li:before {
  left: -6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
}
.tabrow li:after {
  right: -6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
}
.tabrow li.selected:before {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFF;
}
.tabrow li.selected:after {
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabrow">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Consectetur adipisicing</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```